# requirejs, two classes in one file

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I just started out with RequireJS, but i'm stuck at the part where i want to use one js file which has two defines() in it, like this:

**Filename: test.js**

```
define('test1', ['jquery'], function() {
    return {
        method1 : function () {
            console.log("test1 - method 1");
        },

        method2 : function () {
            console.log("test1 - method 2");
        }
    }
});

define('test2', ['jquery'], function() {
    return {
        method1 : function () {
            console.log("test2 - method 1");
        },

        method2 : function () {
            console.log("test2 - method 2");
        }
    }
});
```

I also have a bootstrap,js file which is automatically loaded by the RequireJS framework:

```
require(['jquery', 'test', 'test2'], function ( $, t1, t2 ) {
    console.log(t1);
});
```

It does find the 2nd param, the 'test' file. Only, it returns a '*null*'. It can't find 'test2' because it tries to look for a file called 'test2.js'. Actually i'd like to do something like:

```
require(['jquery', 'test.test1', 'test.test2'], function ( $, t1, t2 ) {
    console.log(t1);
});
```

But in anyway, i'd like to get a handler to both the objects. What am i doing wrong??

Comment: The granularity is at the file level. You can't import parts of a file.  Just import "test.js" and you'll get both objects.

Comment: @Pointy Then there's still something wrong with my code because 'test' returns a null object.

Comment: Ah ... well according to the RequireJS documentation, there should only be **one** module in any given .js file.

Comment: According to this video its possible. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGlDR1QiV3A --- I did the exact same thing. My first define nu only has a function(){} the second one does have a name defined. But still it's looking for a file called test2.js. --- But it indeed works when i only use one define per file. Guess i'll just stick to that.

Comment: if you read the comments on that video you can see that other people were confused too.  I don't think it's a good explanation at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot export two different modules like this. If you want to keep them as "submodules" of 'test', the right way would be to do:

```
define('test', ['jquery'], function() {
    var exports = {};
    exports.test1 = {
        method1 : function () {
            console.log("test1 - method 1");
        },

        method2 : function () {
            console.log("test1 - method 2");
        }
    };

    exports.test2 = {
        method1 : function () {
            console.log("test2 - method 1");
        },

        method2 : function () {
            console.log("test2 - method 2");
        }
    };

    return exports;
});
```

Then you can do:

```
require(['test'], function (test) {
    var test1 = test.test1;
});
```

Comment: If I have two submodules defined there, and I happen to use only one of the modules in my code. Will r.js optimizer only load one of the modules into the final compiled file?