# multiple module in single file SPA

Tags: knockout.js, module, durandal, single-page-application

I have small requirment. I am just started working on simple SPA application. My requirements are to be write class in on .js file and i should able to call individual class in another .js file.

in brief, I have Search,Order and Customer class in one .js file.

```
*globals define*/
define(function(require){
   ...

      return search;
}); 
define(function(require){
   ...

      return order;
}); 
define(function(require){
   ...

      return customer;
});
```

i want to call any one the above module.Is there any solution for this.?

Thanks,
Shiva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way is not allowed. There are other solutions to this problem.

Modules in Durandal are handled by the AMD library [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). In the documentation of the library it says:

> **One module per file.**: Only one module should be defined per JavaScript
>   file, given the nature of the module name-to-file-path lookup
>   algorithm. Multiple modules will be grouped into optimized files by
>   the optimization tool, but you should only use the optimization tool
>   to place more than one module in a file.

As it describes, one option is to optimize multiple modules (multiple files) into one file. ([Optimization doc](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html))

Or you could define one module with multiple objects inside as its described in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9807868/1587864). Using this approach you will not be able to load the objects separatedly, so you will always need to load `search, order` and `customer` objects even if you need only one.